# Selenium test fails when run on a multi-tomcat environment with haproxy

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, testng, haproxy

I have a GUI test (TestNG + Selenium + PhantomJS) that navigates through a couple of panels of my web application.
When I run the test on a single-tomcat environment, everything works correctly.

However, when I switch to a clustered environment (couple of tomcats, behind haproxy), the test fails in a strange way - this is what I see in phantomjsdriver.log:

```
page.onError - msg: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Ext
page.onError - stack:
```

The javascript variable 'Ext' is created by the JS library we're using - ExtJS - so for some reason this library is not getting loaded. There are similar errors for other libraries that we're using.

When I navigate through the application (on the clustered environment) using a regular browser myself, all is fine (of course ;))

Comment: You can try to pass some commandline arguments to PhantomJS through the DesiredCapabilities like `--web-security=false --local-to-remote-url-access=true --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true`.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks! I was just going to try --ignore-ssl-errors, I will check-out all the suggested options next week and let you know if this works.

Comment: @ArtjomB. didn't work :-/ Still fails in exactly the same way... Any other ideas?